# C / Objective C pointer declaration

Tags: objective-c, pointers, floating-point

I have a function that expects a parameter of type `float**`, but I do not know how to declare and initialize this variable.

Can anyone give me any advice on this? Better yet, what type of variable is it? I have been looking into it for days now and any search results comes up empty.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the function in question

```
    - (OSStatus)getBuffersInner:(float**)buffers numberOfBuffers:(int)chnls samples:(int)samples
    {
        int i, j ;
        UInt32 frames ;

        // zero out requested buffers if client needs more channels than exist in the channel map
        for ( i = numberOfMappedChannels; i < chnls; i++ ) memset( buffers[i], 0, samples*sizeof( float ) ) ;

        //  place buffer pointers into bufferList, following the channelMap
        for ( i = 0; i < fileDescriptor.mChannelsPerFrame; i++ ) {
            j = inverseChannelMap[i] ;
            resampledBufferList.list.mBuffers[i].mData = ( j < 0 || j >= chnls ) ? zeros : buffers[j] ;
        }
        frames = samples ;
        return ExtAudioFileRead( audioFileRef, &frames, &resampledBufferList.list ) ;
    }
```

Comment: It's a pointer to a pointer. I'd google a basic tutorial on pointers.

Comment: if you dont know what it is, then how did you write a function expecting it? :-o

Comment: my guess would be that the OP hasn't written the function, and it's a part of a library or something

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is float[n][m] matrix. Something like int main(int argc, char **argv), where argv is an array of 'strings', an array of arrays of char.

Comment: That is not correct. It *can* be used to represent such a matrix, but doesn't have to.

Comment: Yup, it looks like it.I guess it would have helped if I added the function?

Comment: I added the function to my question

Comment: Where did I say it does have to? It could imply a pointer to a pointer to a float but i doubt the author of the function would mean this instead of just requesting a pointer to a value.

Comment: @Björn Pollex: If you look at the code in the question, you'll see it's being used exactly like a 2D array.

Comment: @JeremyP: The answer was written before the OP added the code in question. At that point it was just guessing. If idm edits his answer, I will retract my downvote (can't do that without edit).

Comment: Ok, it was a float matrix. The issue here is that the matrix needs to be created dinamically. The function accepted an allocated "void*" as a valid parameter. Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

This is a pointer-to-pointer. Here is a sample usage:

```
float f = 0.123;
float *pf = &f;
float **ppf = &pf;

cout << *pf << " == " << **ppf << endl;
```

You may want to look into [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/PtrToPtr.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Pointers can be used for several things.  In this case it is probably used for dynamic memory and for changing a (pointer-)value in the function.
So typically, it could be:

```
void getFloat(float** fl)
{
  *fl = new float(1.2);
}

int main()
{
  float* fl;
  getFloat(&fl);
  std::cout << *fl;
  delete fl;
}
```

Mind you that passing parameters as pointers to change is more C-style than C++, although some prefer it over passing references for clarity.
Using raw pointers for dynamic memory is also discouraged in C++.

Comment: Another sensible reason is to write to an array of floats.

Comment: @Michael: yes, thinking of it, that is even more probable as it is used with a primitive and dynamic memory is used more with classes and dynamic arrays.  But in code I've seen, it was usually like I showed, so I could have guessed too quickly.  Still, it is a decent example.

Comment: As shown in the edit of the question, it is in fact a 2D array, with sizes as extra parameters (in a non-C++ function defintion).

Answer (score 0):

```
float **ppfloat = new float*;
*ppfloat = new float;
**ppfloat = 3.14;

delete *ppfloat; //actually deletes the float
delete ppfloat; //actually deletes the pointer to float
```

Just a "pointer to a pointer to float": just break up the sentence.

Comment: What is that `new` operator?  The question is not tagged C++

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `float** buffers` holds a vector of pointers to `float*`. For example, in plain C:

```
size_t numberOfBuffers = ?;
size_t bufferSize = ?;
unsigned i;

typedef float* buffer_t;

buffer_t* buffers = (buffer_t*)malloc(sizeof(buffer_t) * numberOfBuffers);

for(i=0; i<numberOfBuffers; ++i)
{
    buffers[i] = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * bufferSize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you show, it looks like the function is using the
`float**` as a pointer to an array[`chnls] of pointers to
floats[`samples`].  In this case, the best solution is probably to use
something like:

```
std::vector<float> data( chnls * samples );
//  Fill data...
std::vector<float*> args( chnls );
for ( int i = 0; i != args.size(); ++ i ) {
    args[i] = &data[0] + (samples * i);
}
```

And pass `&args[0]` to the function.

(And if this seems complicated, it is.  That's the price we pay for
having to interface C.  If the target function is in C++, there are
much, much better solutions than using `float**`.)